# Перебор значений в json-е

Tags: json, swift

Использую асинхронный метод получения данных. Принимаю *dictionary* из *json*-а. На одной странице расположено 10 новостей.

Хочу по ним пройти, используя цикл

```
for value in dict.key.value
```

но почему-то параметр `value` идёт не по порядку, а в разнобой, и когда я вставляю значения в `tableview`, у меня старые новости могут быть выше в списке, чем новые (т.к. `value` получается вот такой: `41057893`).

Как сделать так, чтобы `value` было по порядку?

Самое забавное, что в *json*-е идет верная нумерация.

Comment: Потому что Dictionary. Создайте класс Новости, в котором будут все данные нормализованные уже из этого JSON'а. Пока проходите по JSON создаете массив их этих объектов, ну а потом сортировочку по любому признаку.

Comment: Я думал, что я делаю, что-то не так... Раз сам Джейсон нормальный, не врубаюсь, почему value не идет по порядку, буду тогда сортировать массив в который заходят значения value

Answer (score 1):

Встроенный Dictionary в Swift не хранит порядок ключей/значений.
Попробуйте использовать упорядоченный словарь:

```
struct OrderedDictionary<KeyType: Hashable, ValueType> {

    typealias ArrayType = [KeyType]
    typealias DictionaryType = [KeyType: ValueType]

    var array = ArrayType()
    var dictionary = DictionaryType()
    var count: Int {
        return self.array.count
    }

    mutating func insert(value: ValueType, forKey key: KeyType, atIndex index: Int) -> ValueType? {
        var adjustedIndex = index

        let existingValue = self.dictionary[key]
        if existingValue != nil {
            let existingIndex = find(self.array, key)!
            if existingIndex < index {
                adjustedIndex--
            }
            self.array.removeAtIndex(existingIndex)
        }
        self.array.insert(key, atIndex:adjustedIndex)
        self.dictionary[key] = value
        return existingValue
    }

    mutating func removeAtIndex(index: Int) -> (KeyType, ValueType) {
        precondition(index < self.array.count, "Index out-of-bounds")
        let key = self.array.removeAtIndex(index)
        let value = self.dictionary.removeValueForKey(key)!
        return (key, value)
    }

    subscript(key: KeyType) -> ValueType? {
        get {
          return self.dictionary[key]
        }
        set {
            if let index = find(self.array, key) {
            } else {
                self.array.append(key)
            }
            self.dictionary[key] = newValue
        }
    }

    subscript(index: Int) -> (KeyType, ValueType) {
        get {
            precondition(index < self.array.count, "Index out-of-bounds")
            let key = self.array[index]
            let value = self.dictionary[key]!
            return (key, value)
        }
    }

}
```

Если ключи и значения, например, строки, то использовать эту структуру можно так:

```
// заполнение словаря:
var dict = OrderedDictionary<String, String>()
dict.insert("dog", forKey: 1, atIndex: 0)
dict.insert("cat", forKey: 2, atIndex: 1)

// получение значений:
var byIndex: (String, String) = dict[0]

// проход по всем значениям:
for i in 0..<dict.count {
    var valueByIndex: (String, String) = dict[i]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте использовать **SwiftyJSON**. С ним гораздо удобнее работать с JSON. Например перебор по массиву будет:

```
for item in json["Items"].array {
}
```